# LEFT JOIN and COUNT two queries difference

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables in my mysql database services and relationships I just need count how many services is in relationships table, so I am trying to do like this

My tables:

- relationships - | relation_id | parent_id |
- services - | service_id | slug_title | title |

Code:

```
SELECT 
    services.slug_title, 
    services.title, 
    COUNT(relationships.parent_id) AS num_companies 
FROM 
    services 
LEFT JOIN 
    relationships ON services.service_id = relationships.parent_id 
GROUP BY 
    services.service_id 
ORDER BY 
    services.title ASC
```

and I have another query

```
SELECT 
    services.slug_title, 
    services.title, 
    COALESCE(companies, 0) AS num_companies 
FROM 
    services 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         parent_id, COUNT(*) AS companies 
     FROM 
         relationships 
     GROUP BY 
         parent_id) relationships ON services.service_id = relationships.parent_id 
ORDER BY 
    services.title ASC
```

Both queries return the same result and are working like I need, but which is better or right to use in better performance way?

Comment: I'd go with the first one, avoiding the inline view you used in the second one ("relationship")

Comment: Note that query 1 has an invalid GROUP BY that wont execute on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries in the `FROM` clause can impede performance in MySQL because they prevent the use of indexes.  That would suggest a preference for the first version.

However, you should consider this version:

```
SELECT s.slug_title, s.title, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM relationships r WHERE s.service_id = r.parent_id
       ) AS num_companies 
FROM services s
ORDER BY s.title ASC;
```

It might seem counter-intuitive that a subquery would have better performance.  However, this query can take advantage of indexes on `relationships(parent_id)` and `services(title, parent_id)` (or even `services(title, service_id, slug_title)`.  And, the doesn't have to do the aggregation on the larger intermediate `JOIN` result.

I should note that that intellectually, I prefer the first version, because I think it is the clearest statement of the result that you want.  However, the correlated subquery is also pretty clear and can have better performance.

Comment: I wil try to use your query, thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use first query. Using a subquery in left join statement is not a processor and ram friendly thing to do as i know.